# integral of a function in a curve

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

let $F=\left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)$
and $R(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ (the curve is a circle with radius 1)

now:
\begin{equation}
\int_{R}F_1.dx+F_2.dy = \int_{0}^{2\pi}-\sin t\ dt  + \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos t\ dt  = 0
\end{equation}
but the book concluded from the Green's theorem that the answer is $2\pi$ (the book take a neighborhood near $0$ (because $0$ is not in the domain) and ...)

so why my answer is wrong and can you give me a solution because I can't understand the solution in the book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector field on the circle is
$$
F=(F_1,F_2)=(-\sin t,\cos t).
$$
Since $(x,y)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ you should also take into account that
$$
(dx,dy)=(x'dt,y'dt)=(-\sin t\,dt,\cos t\,dt).
$$
With 
$$
F_1\,dx+F_2\,dy=(\sin^2t+\cos^2t)\,dt=dt
$$
it makes a simple integration.